# Manage the code from one class in ios

Tags: ios

hi i am using in 10 class viewdidload method these line

```
  SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:23.0f]};

UIButton *settingButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb_menu_icon.png"];
[settingButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[settingButton addTarget:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:settingButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton animated:YES];
```

i want to use it from one class method and import it in any class how can i do this please tell me?

Comment: create base class contain these code in viewDidLoad, your classes will be child of that base class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one class say SWViewController with superclass as UIViewController. Put your above code in viewDidLoad of SWViewController.m. Then change each of your class's superclass as SWViewController.

```
SWViewController.h

@interface SWViewController : UIViewController
{

}

SWViewController.m

@implementation SWViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:23.0f]};

UIButton *settingButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb_menu_icon.png"];
[settingButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[settingButton addTarget:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:settingButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton animated:YES];

}
@end
```

Now Make your view controllers like this :

```
@interface MyViewController : SWViewController
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the method a category method on UIViewController. You'll still need to call it from each viewDidLoad but it's only one line.

Alternatively, if you are presenting everything via a navigation controller, you can make the navigation controller's delegate call the method on each view controller as it is pushed onto the stack.

Creating a base view controller class for this is not a good idea and will bring you too many restrictions.